# Lower Bound for the supreme norm of one matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix and x be a vector. I am wondering if there is a lower bound for $||\Sigma x||_{\infty}$? I know this fact:
$$
\sigma_{min}(A)||B|| \leq ||AB||
$$
I am not sure if it can be used in my case. Thank you.

Comment: All norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, so you can certainly find a bound of the form $\|\Sigma x\| \ge k \sigma_\min (\Sigma) \|x\|$, for some $k>0$ (which is independent of $\Sigma, x$, but dependent on the norms used).

Comment: Thank you. I remember in that formula, both matrix have to be a square matrix. Can it be relaxed to a vector form? I am not quite familiar with the prove of that formula.

Comment: I don't now what you mean by 'relaxed to a vector form' The formula is for a vector norm.

Comment: I mean in this formula $\sigma_{min}(A) ||B|| \leq ||AB||$. Here the norm is actually a operator norm. Could you please explain a little more why $||\Sigma x|| \geq k \sigma_{min}(\Sigma)||x||$ holds? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$\|\Sigma x\|_\infty \ge {1 \over \sqrt{n}}\|\Sigma x\|_2 \ge {1 \over \sqrt{n}}  \sigma_\min(\Sigma) \|x\|_2 \ge {1 \over \sqrt{n}}  \sigma_\min(\Sigma) \|x\|_\infty$.

Here $\sigma_\min(\Sigma)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ (which is
positive semi definite).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation . Is that possible that k doesn't rely on n?

Comment: Not in the above example.