# Upper and lower bound of infinity norm of a matrix-vector product $\lVert A x \rVert_{\infty}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

> Do we have an upper and lower bound of an infinity norm of a matrix-vector product $\lVert A x \rVert_{\infty}$, where $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $x \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{C})$?

---

I can see a lower bound with infinity norm assuming real valued, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500789/lower-bound-for-the-supreme-norm-of-one-matrix-vector-product?rq=1).

So, do we have an upper and lower bound with complex matrix and vector? thank you.

Comment: The lower bound in the link still applies in the complex case. And an obvious upper bound is $\|A\|_\infty\|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I summarize, ${1 \over \sqrt{n}}  \sigma_\min(A) \|x\|_\infty \leq \| A x \|_\infty \leq  \| A \|_\infty  \| x \|_\infty $. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$